# Как отобразить большое количество маркеров

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-api

Добрый день.В приложении есть база данных в которой около 7000 значений.Это клиенты со всеми данными.Я их парсю с сервиса и пытаюсь отобразить все(7000) обьектов как маркеры но телефон зависает а именно  когда хочу в методе onPostExecute  их добавить.Как я понел это иза того что грузится слишком много данных в основном потоке.Но как быть?Что делать

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering?hl=ru

Comment: Показывайте маркеры группами.